# Trying to replace only first instance of a string in Php, replaces all instead

Tags: php, yii

So I have the following string.

```
      John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) , John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,
```

I am trying replace only the first instance of the above John Hotmail however no matter what I try it replaces both. I have looking through the forums for an answer and I have already attempted all of the solutions. I have tried the following.

```
    $string= "/John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,/";
   //$string= "John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,";
    $count = 1;
    $descriptionMessage = $name . ' said hello' . $model->Name . ' to the following people:' . $listParticipants;
    $descriptionMessage = preg_replace($string, "", $descriptionMessage,$count);
```

I have tried similar things with str_replace. I have changed the string message to contain / as well as to have no / in it. I have put count to 0 in which case it does not strip anything out and I have put it to 1 as above which removes both John Hotmail strings. None of the settings I have entered have just removed the first occurance however and I do not know why. I am currently using this code in a controller class of the Yii Framework if that helps. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It don't quite understand what you are trying a achieve, can you try rephrasing your questions so it is easier to answer. It looks like I need more information and what is contained in $name and $listParticipants - if you describe what you are trying to do then there could be another possible solution.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the lack of clarity, the $listParticipants is just the string containing John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) , John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,. The $name is just a name to put into the string, the name will be different to the $listParticipants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the first occurrence:

```
$string = 'John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,';
$descriptionMessage = 'John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) , John Hotmail(johnhotmail@hotmail.com) ,';

$position = strpos($descriptionMessage, $string);
if ($position !== false) {
    $descriptionMessage = substr_replace($descriptionMessage, '', $position , strlen($string));
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked a charm. Thank you very much good sir! On a side note do you have any idea why the str_replace and preg_replace was not working?

Comment: No problem, not sure why the preg_replace doesn't work but the code in the answer will be faster than regex anyway.